# Getting a query to index seek (rather than scan)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

Running the following query (SQL Server 2000) the execution plan shows that it used an index seek and Profiler shows it's doing 71 reads with a duration of 0.

```
select top 1 id from table where name = '0010000546163' order by id desc
```

Contrast that with the following with uses an index scan with 8500 reads and a duration of about a second.

```
declare @p varchar(20)
select @p = '0010000546163'
select top 1 id from table where name = @p order by id desc
```

Why is the execution plan different? Is there a way to change the second method to seek?

thanks

**EDIT**

Table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [table] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (13) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL)
```

Id is primary clustered key
There is a non-unique index on Name and a unique composite index on id/name 
There are other columns - left them out for brevity

Comment: What datatypes/schema please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you've added the schema, please try this. SQL Server treats length differences as different data types and will convert the `varchar(13)` column to match the `varchar(20)` variable

```
declare @p varchar(13)
```

If not, what about collation coercien? Is the DB or server different to the column?

```
declare @p varchar(13) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
```

If not, add this before and post results

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
GO
```

Comment: Thanks so much - changing to varchar(13) did the trick. I had no idea the size of the variable could change the execution plan. Could you explain why? And thanks again.

Comment: @PaulB: varchar(13) will be changed to varchar(20) which the index will be ignored and scan happens = slower... very late reply sorry

Answer (score 0):

If the name column is NVARCHAR then u need your parameter to be also of the same type. It should then pick it up by index seek.

```
declare @p nvarchar(20)
select @p = N'0010000546163'
select top 1 id from table where name = @p order by id desc
```

Comment: It would convert @p to nvarchar because it has a higher precedence, not the column