# T-SQL Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following table in SQL Server 2000:

```
TABLE_NAME         |     COLUMN_NAME      |     TYPE_NAME      |    PRECISION    |    LENGTH  |    SCALE        |
test                     TestID                 int                 10                   4            0
test                     TestDecimal            decimal             18                   20           2
test                     TestFloat              float               15                   8            NULL
test                     TestMoney              money                19                   21            4
```

My question is, if I wanted to created a stored procedure that takes 4 parameters based on my table fields, how do I do this. I have this solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc ( @TestID int, @TestDecimal decimal, @TestFloat float, @TestMoney money ) 
AS
.....
.....
.....
GO
```

This works, except I think @TestDecimal loses its decimal portion, thus converting it into a whole number. Do I need to put @TestDecimal decimal(Precision,Scale) instead of just decimal? and if so, is there any other numeric datatypes that I need to specify this type of parameter encoding?

Comment: You win the award for nicest looking table definition I've seen so far (and I've seen a few here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to specifc (18,2) for decimal/numeric

The same applies to float/real, (n)varchar, (n)char, (var)binary, datetime2 (missed any?)

A different precision, scale or length is in effect a different datatype and a conversion will occur.

[Example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211287/getting-a-query-to-index-seek-rather-than-scan/1211787#1211787) of why differenmt varchar lengths make different datatypes

Comment: You'd presumably only have to specify scale and precision if they're other than the default. (I've never specified it for any of my floats and reals.)

Comment: @Philip: I'd always specify except for float/real (which I don't really use). For example I wouldn't rely on varchar length = 30 in a CAST: I'd define explicitly, especially decimal because of how * and / are handled (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/)

Comment: Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter type must match the database column type. A database type is defined not only by its base type, but also by its actual length and precision, when it applies. `TestDecimal` id actualy `DECIMAL(18,2)` in your example.