# Reference to table without foreign key constraint

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a database and an application that edits the database

I have a table with addresses called ADDRESS (ID, STREETID, NUMBER)

I have a table with street names called STREET (ID, STREETNAME, CREATIONUSERID)

I also have a table with my users called USER (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD)

The street names in my table STREET are already filled.
The table is used by users as a look up table
to enter an address (field ADDRESS.STREETID) somewhere in my application,
but sometimes the user has to enter a new street
that will be inserted into STREET for further use.
When a user adds a street to my table I want to be able
to keep track of which user made the addition.

Now there are 2 options as I think about it:

1st: **Create a false user** where the default streets of STREET 
will refer to and then create a foreign key constraint 
(STREET.CREATIONUSERID that refers to USER.ID) for the new streets created

2nd: **Create no foreign key constraint**, leave CREATIONUSERID null
for the default streets of STREET and update it only for the new
streets created to keep track of the user that added each

***Which is better and why?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use foreign key.It will enforce the referential integrity

[Check the link for the advantages of foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629537/sql-server-foreign-key-constraint-benefits)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Reading it, I just realized that a foreign key can have NULL values, so this would be the best solution for me. I will create a foreign key constraint for CREATIONUSERID, while making it 'nullable'

Answer (score 0):

What do you intend to do when some user of your system stops being one, and must thence be removed from your USER table ?

Comment: I also have a field USER.STATUS which is a flag of the user's state. In case a user must be deleted I will set it to 'deleted'. This way I keep the history of this user, while setting him innactive.